# Why does an eutectic liquid not change composition on solidifying?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, physical-chemistry

Callen remarks that "If it is desired to have the solid precipitate with the same composition as the liquid, it is necessary to start with a liquid of" eutectic composition. Why is this so? I think this has something to do with how the composition of the liquid phase in general changes during the solidification process in an $r$ component system, $r>1$, but it's not clear to me how freezing at the eutectic composition prevents this.

Comment: While the solid may have the same overall composition as the eutectic melt, it is split into two solid phases, so the wording could be better. But away from the eutectic, you have one solid phase forming, well away from the liquid composition, and the liquid composition changes as solidification progresses. Look at the phase diagram.

Comment: Noneutectic compositions pass through a two-phase region as they freeze, with varying compositions freezing as mediated by the [lever rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lever_rule), as shown in the first two slides [here](https://www.chem.tamu.edu/rgroup/hughbanks/courses/462/handouts/Phase_Diagram_supplement.pdf).

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you, that first sentence is very helpful in clarifying. I suppose the key is that, since the liquid freezes in one fell swoop at $T_e$, there is no range of temperatures over which the composition of the liquid changes.

Comment: Thank you, @Chemomechanics . Those two slides are very helpful. If you'd like to even post that as an answer I'd be glad to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On either side of a eutectic lie slushy (i.e., two-phase) regions (here marked α+L and L+β, with L being liquid and α and β being impure A and B, respectively):

[image]

(This and similar images from Shackelford.)

Here, both the solid and liquid Gibbs free energies $G$ are pretty low, so Nature splits the difference and lets the material at that composition decompose into a little of both:

[image]

(Image from Porter and Easterling.)

Progressive cooling from the liquid through one of these regions yields crystallites of the relevant solid, with composition determined by the [lever rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lever_rule) (with constant composition assumed for simplicity, corresponding to slow cooling); then, the remaining liquid freezes into a fine eutectic microstructure because both α and β favorably exist as solids:

[image]

One can avoid the included crystallites by freezing at exactly the eutectic composition:

[image]

As shown in the Gibbs free energy plots above, this is the composition that happens to be the last point that intersects the convex hull formed by L, α, and β as L rises out of this contour, now energetically unfavorable.

Comment: Thank you! Your last sentence in particular is tremendously helpful in connecting the discussion to the underlying fundamental relations. I am accepting now, though I am interested in your comment that we proceed “with constant composition assumed for simplicity, corresponding to slow cooling”. Is this so that we can assume things are quasistatic and the system is everywhere characterized by an overall (across both phases) mole fraction of component 1 which is constant (at the value at which it was initially introduced)?

Comment: The overall fractions of A and B are always the same, but if you cool quickly, you'll get compositional variations within the crystallite that won't have time to even out before they're kinetically frozen in place. See Fig. 9.5 [here](https://anupturnedworld.files.wordpress.com/2016/06/callister-materials-science-and-engineering.pdf), for example.

Comment: Good old Callister. Clearly I’ve forgotten a lot. From glancing there the idea is that near the crystallite the liquid is enriched (or diluted) depending on if we’re near the alpha or beta side, but that far from the crystallite the liquid will have the same composition as the original?